# How to know junction LatLng points in android google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I m using the following method to get directions between two points in google map in my android application.

```
public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }
```

Now i have a list of LatLng to draw the polyline. But i want to identify only the junction LatLngs on that particular path. How to identify only the junction LatLng amoung all the LatLng listed in my arraylist?

I'm new to android so please give me a detailed answer.
If my English is not clear please leave a comment, i ll try to improve the question.
Thanks in advance.